# Spring Boot Admin on Docker does not see other applications on Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, docker, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot Admin app running on Docker.
My problem is it displays other applications running on Docker as offline.
Applications running elsewhere are displayed just fine.

Could anyone help and tell me how to configure or what to add to applications? Thanks in advance

EDIT: The problem is with Docker, other applications running with similar configurations are online in admin app, only the docker ones aren't

EDIT2: 
Error:

```
{"timestamp":1506501630423,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException","message":"Connect to IP_ADDRESS] failed: connect timed out"}
```

Comment: Are all the dockers in the same network?

Comment: yes, all of them are in the same network (overlay, scope:swarm), problems also occurs with hystrix - it does not display applications from docker. Eureka sees all of them

Comment: Can you share the configuration or relevant code, otherwise is difficult to guess...

Comment: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-samples/spring-boot-admin-sample-eureka it is this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was mistaken - **my applications in docker are not in the same network**. When I put them in the same network it started to work.
That is a different problem, so I close the topic. 
Thank you and sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) dependency in the rest of projects?

If not you need to include it:

Maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
}
```

So let's say that you're running 3 Apps: A, B and C. 
If you add the dependency to only A and B you wil see that, after restart them, A and B will display as ONLINE or UP and C will keep as OFFLINE.

**Update:**

After checking your `docker-compose.yml` file I saw a TYPO:

In the eureka service you have set:

```
environment:
  - EUREKA_INSTANCE_PREFERIPADDRESS=true
```

And it should be:

```
environment:
  - EUREKA_INSTANCE_PREFER_IP_ADDRESS=true
```

Also, if this environment config doesn't work try with:

```
environment:
  - EUREKA_INSTANCE_PREFER_IP_ADDRESS="true"
```

Comment: not really, everyone of my apps have actuator dependency already, they display fine in eureka. There is a problem with apps that are running on docker.

Comment: @KompiKompi please check my updated answer, I saw a TYPO in your docker-compose